# Детские деньги: нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Нужно ли кавычить "детские", когда речь идет о деньгах на детей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кавычки нужно поставить, так слово "детские" в данном случае  употреблено в условном значении - применительно к определенному контексту.

Comment: У нас с коллегами как раз спор о том, есть ли условность. Если деньги предназначены для детей и для расходования на детей, то это одно из значений прилагательного "детские" и кавычки не нужны. Или не совсем предназначены для детей? Или проблема в том, что возникает двусмысленность (детские деньги еще и игровые)? Или это не совсем точная, корявая трансформация конструкции "деньги на детей" (игрушки для детей = детские игрушки, а деньги на детей не совсем детские)?

Comment: Относительное прилагат. «детский» сочетается со значительным количеством существительных, при этом значение таких выражений определяется однозначно: детские товары, детское питание и др. С некоторыми сущ. слово или не сочетается вообще, или значение  сочетания понимается только из контекста – в таком случае требуются кавычки. «Детские» деньги – это могут быть деньги, которые государство выделяет в помощь родителям, или которые родители откладывают на целевые нужды для детей, или которые дают им на карманные расходы и т.д. Конкретное значение словосочетания можно определить только  по тексту.